# indexing in oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have a table

```
Name | Postal_CODE
```

I have created an index on Postal_Code as

```
CREATE INDEX MNO on Table1(Postal_code).
```

but, when i see the execution plan of

```
select * from Table1 where Postal_code is not null
```

it show's full scan for Table1.It does not make use of index.
Any idea why?

Comment: How many rows are there in your table?

Comment: Can you post the explain plan too?

Comment: How many of the 13 million are NULL?

Comment: Also, does the explain plan show a full table scan or an Index Fast Full Scan?

Comment: IT SHOWS "TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE"

Answer (score 4):

Oracle's BTree indexes do not store null values. It means that you need to get all rows from index and in this case it will be faster to use full scan.

Answer (score 1):

If more than 10% (approx) of the rows in the table have postal_codes, then it's more efficient for Oracle to do a fast full scan or full table scan than use the index.

(10% is a very rough rule of thumb.  YMMV.)

Comment: I would have thought it would execute an Index Fast Full Scan if that were the case?

Comment: I just tested on a table with 16.3 million rows, the overwhelming majority are not null and only a few nulls, the count of NOT NULL values used the index fast full scan. Oracle 10g (10.2.0.4)

Comment: You're quite right, my bad.  I was mostly focusing on the "won't use an index part", rather than correctly identifying the scan type.  Answer amended.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, Oracle will not store a reference to rows where Postal_code is null.  Therefore it will not use the index. It's not quite that simple either as Oracle may have determined that the cost of using the index is more expensive than doing a tablescan.